# VB.NET 2010 Express Dataset/Dataview problems with XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, dataset, xmlreader, dataview

I am a co-op student learning vb.net and I have a project which retrieves data from an xml file within the program (based on selections made from combo boxes) and calculates and displays prices.

My XML looks like this:
    <.Root>
        ....<.Processes>
    ........<.Process>12345<./Process >
       ........<.12345Material_Process>This Process<./12345Material_Process >
    ........<.Rate>20<./Rate >
    ........<.Type>Nitrogen<./Type >
    ........<.Dia>0.125<./Dia >
        .
        .
        .
    ...<./Processes>
    ....<.Machines>
    ........<.Machine>AB12345
    ........<.Machine_Type>12345 4000 <./Machine_Type >
    ........<.AB12345Bed_Size>4000<./AB12345Bed_Size >
    ........<.Base_Price>$831.00<./Base_Price >
        .
        .
        .
    ....<./Machines>
<./Root>
*Periods are for display (Couldn't figure out how to display xml code, I am that new with code!)

I have one combobox that loads data from the Processes section just fine, but then another uses the same method and gets an "IndexOutOfRange" error or "Column AB12345Bed_Size Not Found" even though I am using the same method for both. For "Processes" I am using DataView.Sort on "<12345Material_Process>" which reflects the selecteditem in the combobox. The program retrieves that row without a problem.
Here is the code that is giving me a problem:

> ```
>    Dim xmlFile As XmlReader    
>    xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("File.xml", New XmlReaderSettings())  
>    Dim ds As New DataSet  
>    Dim dv As DataView  
>    ds.ReadXml(xmlFile)  
>
>    dv = New DataView(ds.Tables(0))
>    dv.Sort = strName & "Bed_Size"
>    Dim index As Integer = dv.Find(cmbSize.SelectedItem)
> ```
>
> I have read msdn and tried to make sense of it, as well as searching through many forums and examples.
>   Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So obviously I don't know XML very well. I renamed the "<.Machines>" tags as "<.Processes>" and now it works. Now that I think about it I had a similar problem before.
So I guess I'd better sign up early for that XML class next term!